# systemd-networkd - interface goes down while renewing lease

Tags: dhcp, systemd-networkd

I am using Ubuntu as my home router and since migrating from Funtoo/Gentoo, I noticed I periodically have connection drops whereas I did not before.  Looking further at the logs, I see my external interface going down right @ the T1 time (half of the DHCP lease).

I am using netplan to configure my system with systemd-networkd as the dispatcher.

I *thought* that I could mark the connection as critical via /etc/systemd/networkd.conf:

```
[DHCP]
CriticalConnection=true

UseDNS=false
UseNTP=false
```

However, that doesn't appear to do anything.

I am referencing the documentation here:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/systemd.network.5.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I placed the file in the wrong place, it needed to be put here:

/etc/systemd/network/*.network

Where * can be whatever you like.  For me, I named it default (default.network).